# Calculate Intersection with a Non Finite Set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

What is the best way to answer Intersection or Union based questions with a set that is not finite?

such as this:

Calculate: $A \cap B$

$$\begin{align}
A&=\{x\mid x=n+9, n\in\mathbb N\}\\
B&=\{x\mid x=4n+1,n\in\mathbb N\}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Think of intersection as "and", as in $A \cap B$ satisfies the conditions of $A$ AND $B$.

On the other hand, think of union as "or", as in $A \cup B$ satisfies the conditions of $A$ OR $B$.

Comment: I know the difference between AND and OR, but my question is how to calculate the elements in the set when the set is non finite

Comment: You don't calculate it, you write the set as $A\cap B=\{x\mid \text{some condition on }x\}$, the same way $A$ and $B$ are written.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - What about the power set?

Comment: The power set is a different animal, but the power set of $A$ is written as $\{x\mid x\subseteq A\}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews For example: If I wanted to calculate the power set of B \ A, and the set is infinite, how many elements from each of the set would you use?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume $\mathbb{N}= \{1,2,3,\ldots,\}$; if you use the definition that $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$, the solution is almost the same.

Note that $A=\{10,11,12,\ldots\}$ (integers greater than $9$), and $B=\{5,9,13,17,\ldots\}$. The intersection of the two sets are the numbers that appear in both $A$ and $B$; you just need to find a way to describe them.

> There is more than one way to express it, but any answer might feel tautological or like circular reasoning... here is one answer. $A \cap B = \{x \mid x=4n+1, n \in \{3,4,5,\ldots\}\}$.

Comment: There is another answer more in keeping with the format of the original question, without using the vague notation $\{3,4,5,\dots\}$, which isn't formal...

Answer (score 0):

I assume  $\mathbb N= \{0,1,..\}$, otherwise a little change will be needed.
$$A \cap B=\{x\mid (x=n+9)\land(x=4m+1);\ n,m\in\mathbb N\}=\{4m+1\in \{9, 10,\cdots\}\}=\{9,13,17,\cdots\}$$

$$A \cup B=\{x\mid (x=n+9)\lor(x=4m+1);\ m, n\in\mathbb N\}.$$ Just think about $m,n=0,1, 2,3,\cdots$.

may be diagram below can help. 
(horizontal line is for $n$ and vertical is for $x$).

[image]